# React routing with express is working on page refresh

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router-dom

My project using express for server and React for frontEnd. Routes are like this

```
 <Router >
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomeContainer} />
        <Route path="/women" component={SectionContainer} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

To serve these routes my server js has

```
 server.get('*', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'));
 });
```

Page url http://localhost:3000/women is working only on page refresh, first time click on url is just changing the browser url with no page update. But on page refresh it is working perfectly fine.
Please suggest what i am missing.

Comment: Could you include your entire topmost React component? [Your code works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/k9l5qm3845).

Comment: Only react is working fine, problem is when same code is integrated with  epress server, i am also using webpack.

Comment: Yes, but you say that "first time click on url is just changing the browser url with no page update". That sounds like a React Router issue and not a server issue, since the routing is done in the browser.

Comment: Could you describe the full setup? On what port does the Express backend run? What does the full index.js of the React frontend look like? Just an idea, since I had similar caching related issues that were caused by React's service worker. The service worker caches every asset and only refreshes them on reload if necessary. You can unregister it at least temporarily in order to rule it out as the cause: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#opting-out-of-caching

Comment: Here is my code base -https://github.com/khus29/shoppingcart Work is still in progress

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issue. I found HashRouter helpful than the BrowserRouter:

```
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Using HasRouter will be working fine as it keeps state on every history data changes.